# Understanding hook_finder

Tags: c, portable-executable

I'm Trying to understand the PE Format & the source code of "hook_finder" in here
"https://github.com/Mr-Un1k0d3r/EDRs/blob/main/hook_finder64.c"

in this snippet I now it's trying to calculate Export_Table offset:

```
VOID DumpListOfExport(VOID *lib, BOOL bNt) {
    DWORD dwIter = 0;
    CHAR* base = (CHAR*)lib;
    CHAR* PE = base + (unsigned char)*(base + 0x3c); 
    DWORD ExportDirectoryOffset = *((DWORD*)PE + (0x8a / 4));
    CHAR* ExportDirectory = base + ExportDirectoryOffset;
    DWORD dwFunctionsCount = *((DWORD*)ExportDirectory + (0x14 / 4));
    DWORD OffsetNamesTableOffset = *((DWORD*)ExportDirectory + (0x20 / 4));
    CHAR* OffsetNamesTable = base + OffsetNamesTableOffset;

    printf("------------------------------------------\nBASE\t\t\t0x%p\t%s\nPE\t\t\t0x%p\t%s\nExportTableOffset\t0x%p\nOffsetNameTable\t\t0x%p\nFunctions Count\t\t0x%x (%d)\n------------------------------------------\n",
    base, base, PE, PE, ExportDirectory, OffsetNamesTable, dwFunctionsCount, dwFunctionsCount);

    for(dwIter; dwIter < dwFunctionsCount - 1; dwIter++) {
        DWORD64 offset = *((DWORD*)OffsetNamesTable + dwIter);
        CHAR* current = base + offset;
        GetBytesByName((HANDLE)lib, current, bNt);
    }
}
```

ox3c is e_lfnew offset. However, can't understand what's other hex values and why it's divided by 4 byte?

Further,

```
VOID GetBytesByName(HANDLE hDll, CHAR *name, BOOL bNt) {
    FARPROC ptr = GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hDll, name);
    DWORD* opcode = (DWORD*)*ptr;

    if(bNt) {
        if(name[0] != 'N' && name[1] != 't') {
            return;
        }
    }
    
    if((*opcode << 24) >> 24 == 0xe9) {
        if(!IsFalsePositive(name)) {
            printf("%s is hooked\n", name);
        }
    }
}
```

what's been exactly left & right shifting and Why 24 specifically?
From my understanding of EDRs, it adds a JMP instruction at the very beginning of the function and that's why the condition is trying to check if it's (0xe9), but how does it follow and be certain about the function flow?

and is this applicable only for ntdll.dll?

Sorry I'm starting to study the PE behavior and trying to make things very clear.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It appears that the author has a fondness for dword over byte, so counting is done in dwords and then divided by 4 to get the byte count --- and reading a dword only to extract the first byte (the 24-bit shifts) is a bit silly, if you ask me - why not just read the byte directly? Oh, well.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error
What do u mean reading just the byte? how would it be compared to jmp. I think the 24-bit shift is for formatting only?or maybe no? I mean to get it in "0xe9". but I can't really understand what've been  compared actually, like how would I know it is @ the very beginning of the function? to compare it to jmp in the first palce? I don't now if I made my self clear of what I really wanna know but please bear me with me :)

Comment: An x86/64 instruction that starts with the byte `0xe9` is a jump. This code reads a full dword but then only looks at the first byte of memory to determine that, but I'm arguing that it would be easier to understand, and just as efficient to  use `opcode` as a byte pointer.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I see, but how does it check it starts with jump? meaning how it follows the DLL behavior?? because I checked "ntdll.dll" using CFF, export directory contains the APIs used but nothing starts with e9.. I know this might be a dump question to ask, but in what criteria the condition is made?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember the exact details off the top of my head. If you're curious download the Portable Executable specification and look it up there - it's on Microsoft's site.

Comment: OK. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `DumpListOfExport` assumes that [`NtHeaders`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_nt_headers64) start at the offset **0x3c** from the base but, this is not always the case depending on the size of the DOS stub. Probably, this code makes that assumption for `ntdll.dll`.

And in the function `GetBytesByName`, if first byte of the procedure starts with a [`JMP`](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_147.html)(in that case, it is near, relative jmp whose opcode starts with **"E9"**) instruction and the procedure name is not in the false positives list, then the function makes decision that the function is hooked.

Let be the value of the 4-bytes pointed to by `opcode` **0xca0e4be9**, left shifting it by 24 will result in **0xe9000000**, and then right shifting by 24 the result will be 0x000000e9 which is the value of the first byte at `ptr`.

That procedure can be simplified as follows.

```
VOID GetBytesByName(HANDLE hDll, CHAR *name, BOOL bNt) {
    FARPROC ptr = GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hDll, name);
    BYTE* opcode = (BYTE*)ptr;

    if(bNt) {
        if(name[0] != 'N' && name[1] != 't') {
            return;
        }
    }
    
    if(!IsFalsePositive(name) && *opcode == 0xe9) {
        printf("%s is hooked\n", name);
    }
}
```

***As a note*** : *I can say that the code isn't written well, and doesn't follow any good coding style.*

Comment: So, if the "0x3c" is the offset from the base, what does ("0x8a, 0x14, 0x20" ) represent? Sorry I looked up MSDN & can't see where did it come from.

Comment: The official PE specification doesn't provide the offsets. These values can be obtained from the corresponding data structures in `winnt.h` header file. 0x8A is the offset of the **Export Table Entry** in **Optional Header Data Directories**. The others are related to [Export Table Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#the-edata-section-image-only) Format.